# Get a strings between brackets with regular expressions and php preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have several texts with custom macro tags in it. I want to parse the content of these tags but I'd like to treat the ones with parameters in it differently.

I need to construct valid URLs out of these bracket contents.

**Example:**

This is my text:

> {gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day,single=IMG_0336.jpg,salign=left{/gallery}
>
> Hey there! We had a great day with a tough but funny competition. Our
>   team had a great race and was able to finish in second place.
>
> {gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day{/gallery}
>
> {gallery}team/members{/gallery}

So I need to extract the path parts of the string between the {gallery} tags but I don't want to match those with parameters such as "single=IMG_0336.jpg,salign=left" because these are treated separately.

I need something which does the following:

> {gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day,single=IMG_0336.jpg,salign=left{/gallery}

becomes

> first output: events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day
>
> second output: IMG_0336.jpg

and

> {gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day{/gallery}

becomes

> events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day

Tried the following regex:

```
/\{gallery\}(.*?)(?!single=)\{\/gallery\}/
```

But it allways matches the whole string including the single parameter.

To get the content of the single parameter I tried the following:

```
/,single=(.*?),/
```

This works fine for the single paramter only but I don't know how to get everything together.

**Conclusion:**

In a PHP environment I would like to have as output two arrays. The first consists only of the folders:

- events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day
- team/members

and a second array which consists of the single file paths:

- events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Dayist/IMG_0336.jpg

Comment: you are confusing. first you say you dont want to match `those with parameters`, then you immediately give examples where you DO match them..

Comment: I will edit the question to be more clear

Comment: Have a look at [`\{gallery\}(.*?)(?:,single=([^,}]+).*?)?\{\/gallery\}`](https://regex101.com/r/1dC47h/3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will extract your desired substrings and prepare the output data as you have requested:  [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vR2ssJ/1)

PHP Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e56169aff322a5d5e9c79b1cbe220902786bfc0))

```
$str="{gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day,single=IMG_0336.jpg,salign=left{/gallery}

Hey there! We had a great day with a tough but funny competition. Our team had a great race and was able to finish in second place.

{gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day{/gallery}

{gallery}team/members{/gallery}";
preg_match_all('@\{gallery\}([^,]*?)(?:,single=([^,{]+).*?)?\{/gallery\}@',$str,$out);

// Matches array:
var_export($out);

echo "\n\n---\n\n";

// Folders only array:
var_export(array_filter(array_slice($out,1)[0],'strlen'));

echo "\n\n---\n\n";

// Path + Image files array:
foreach($out[2] as $i=>$v){
    if($v){
        $result[]="{$out[1][$i]}/$v";
    }
}
var_export($result);\
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '{gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day,single=IMG_0336.jpg,salign=left{/gallery}',
    1 => '{gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day{/gallery}',
    2 => '{gallery}team/members{/gallery}',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day',
    1 => 'events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day',
    2 => 'team/members',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'IMG_0336.jpg',
    1 => '',
    2 => '',
  ),
)

---
// Folders only array:
array (
  0 => 'events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day',
  1 => 'events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day',
  2 => 'team/members',
)

---
// Path + Image files array:
array (
  0 => 'events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day/IMG_0336.jpg',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
<?php
$str=getstr();
preg_match_all('/\{gallery\}(.*?)\{\/gallery\}/u',$str,$matches);
$parsed=[];
foreach($matches[1] as $match){
    $tmp=[];
    $match=explode(',',$match);
    foreach($match as $tmp2){
        $tmp2=explode("=",$tmp2);
        assert(count($tmp2)<=2);
        if(count($tmp2)>1){
            $tmp[$tmp2[0]]=$tmp2[1];
        }else{
            $tmp[]=$tmp2[0];
        }
    }
    $parsed[]=$tmp;
}
var_dump($parsed);


function getstr():string{
    $str=<<<'STR'
{gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day,single=IMG_0336.jpg,salign=left{/gallery}

Hey there! We had a great day with a tough but funny competition. Our team had a great race and was able to finish in second place.

{gallery}events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day{/gallery}

{gallery}team/members{/gallery}
STR;
return $str;
}
```

$parsed[0][0] contains `events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day` ,

$parsed [0]["single"] contains `IMG_0336.jpg`

$parsed [0]["salign"] contains `left`

$parsed[1][0] contains `events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day`

$parsed[2][0] contains `team/members`

full output of the var_dump is

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(33) "events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day"
    ["single"]=>
    string(12) "IMG_0336.jpg"
    ["salign"]=>
    string(4) "left"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(33) "events/2016-02-18-Sunny-Sport-Day"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "team/members"
  }
}
```